# Program won't print complete words just single letters

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python and am trying to make a small game for a college assignment. I am trying to print a randomly selected word from a few external text files (with harder words in each one) and have it displayed for 2 seconds, the word then disappears and the user has to spell it. At the moment my program just displays a random letter from the text file and no whole words.

```
print ("""Welcome to the Spelling Game
What difficulty do you want to play?
Easy, Medium or Hard?""")
strDifficulty = input().upper

if strDifficulty is ("EASY"):
    with open ('EASY.txt', 'r') as f:
        (chosen) = f.readlines()

if strDifficulty is ("MEDIUM"):
    with open ('MEDIUM.txt', 'r') as f:
        (chosen) = f.readlines()

if strDifficulty is ("HARD"):
    with open ('HARD.txt', 'r') as f:
        (chosen) = f.readlines()

import random
x = ('chosen')
print (random.choice (x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple issues with your code why it would print out a single character:

`strDifficulty = input().upper` does not uppercase input from the command line. It will read something you type, which is a string (`str` in python) and assign the method `upper` of that string to `strDifficulty`. What you're likely looking for is `strDifficulty = input().upper()` (the extra parentheses will *call* the method upper, returning an uppercased version of what is read from standard in.

`x = ('chosen')` is assigning the string `'chosen'` to x, not the value of the variable `chosen`. You might have meant `x = chosen`, assigning the value of `chosen` to `x`.

`print (random.choice(x))` isn't far off, but will choose a random element from `x`. As `x` is always the string `'chosen'`, you'll likely get one of those letters. You could simply remove the line `x = ('chosen')` and call `print(random.choice(chosen))`.

There's plenty more to be said about your piece of code, but let's start here :)

Comment: Ok, I've added the parentheses to the strDifficulty = input().upper line, removed the x = ('chosen') and changed the print (random.choice(x)) to print(random.choice(chosen)) as you suggested. I'm now getting an error saying NameError: Name 'chosen' is not defined. I think this happened before and thats why I added the whole x= bit.

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected because you're using `is` to compare strings, while strings should be compared using `==`. @Farzan-Haijan's answer (while not explaining why) includes this; the code in his answer should implement what you were trying to accomplish :)

Comment: yep, all working now, for future reference when should IS be used?

Comment: There's plenty resources on this, but `is` tests whether the two things on the left and right are really the same object. So mostly, you'll want to do this only for checking if you have the same *instance* of something (maybe a class you defined yourself) or whether something is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications to your code.

```
print ("""Welcome to the Spelling Game
What difficulty do you want to play?
Easy, Medium or Hard?""")
strDifficulty = input().upper()

if strDifficulty=="EASY":
    with open ('EASY.txt', 'r') as f:
        chosen = f.readlines()

if strDifficulty=="MEDIUM":
    with open ('MEDIUM.txt', 'r') as f:
        chosen = f.readlines()

if strDifficulty=="HARD":
    with open ('HARD.txt', 'r') as f:
        chosen = f.readlines()

import random
print (random.choice (chosen))
```